# Heroku Rails 7 deployment not finding Javascript files (404)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a rails app that has javascript working correctly locally but when I push to Heroku it's getting 404s for each of the relative imports in my application.js file:

```
// Simply importing activates Turbo Drive
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

// Here we use relative imports so these aren't in import map
import HelloController from "./application/hello_controller";
import "./application/logstuff";
import "./application/main";

// Start Stimulus and register controllers
window.Stimulus = Application.start();
window.Stimulus.debug = false; // set true to enable stimulus debugging
Stimulus.register("hello", HelloController);
```

I have my javascript in app/javascript but the error messages read like the javascript is missing from app/assets/:

```
GET <url>/assets/application/hello_controller net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Am I missing a config somewhere to switch where to look for the javascript?

Thanks :)

Comment: During Heroku deployment do you see the assets being precompiled by Heroku ? You can try to precompile locally : `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile` and then push to Heroku buth then you will have to find out why assets are not precompiled at Heroku

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response - it does seem to be compiling correctly during deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and resolved it by changing the contents of my app/javascript/controllers/index.js file to this:

```
import { application } from "controllers/application"
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

More info here ->
https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/issues/87

Comment: Thank you - I ended up here after running ```rails stimulus:manifest:update``` while following a tutorial, and it totally botched my Heroku deployment even though the app worked in my dev environment. Your answer gave me the clues to figure out that reverting index.js would solve the issue. +1 and thanks.

Comment: Nice - mind giving my answer an upvote? And yes... I am shamelessly shilling for upvotes

Comment: I did already actually, your answer was voted to -1 before. Sigh.

Comment: That's a bummer - but thanks for the plus 1 I suppose

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, but it worked well for me after following these steps:

1. In `config/importmap.rb`

```
pin_all_from "app/javascript/yourfolder", under: "yourfolder";
```

2. In `application.js` (no need for "./" and extension is not required):

```
import 'yourfolder/yourfile';
```